# Remove white spaces between specific characters only

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove some white spaces between specific characters only.
This is my data:

```
#1 2 5 1#
#   5 5 3#: 100% #5 55#
#554     #: 23    
#559#: 30%
#4 79#: 2 0 0#%
#473#: 20 #47  4#
#4  7  4 43 33 5 5#: 15s
#4 79#: 195%
#473#: 20 # 474#
#475#: 14.5s
```

I want all of the whitespaces between two # # tags, that are not separated by anything other than numbers, removed.
My data should look like this:

```
#1251#
#553#: 100% #555#
#554#: 23    
#559#: 30%
#479#: 2 0 0#%
#473#: 20 #474#
#474433355#: 15s
#479#: 195%
#473#: 20 #474#
#475#: 14.5s
```

I'm currently trying to use the following regex in PHP to preg_replace those whitespaces, however, everything I've tried was unsuccessful.

```
(?:[#])(?:([\s])*[0-9]*)*(?:[#])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YkW1Z3XVrhF4RSSw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex targets all the spaces you want. You can `preg_replace` them with empty strings.

```
(?:#|\G)\d*\K\s+(?=[\d\s]*#)
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nS7jE9)

As a second option, since your lines seem to be starting with `#`, to avoid an imbalance building up between the `#`, you can also use:

```
(?m)(?:^#|\G)\d*\K\s+(?=[\d\s]*#)
```

**Explanation**

```
(?:#|\G)\d*\K\s+(?=[\d\s]*#)
```

- Match the regular expression below `(?:#|\G)`

  - Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `#`

    - Match the character “#” literally `#`
  - Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) `\G`

    - Assert position at the start of the match attempt (the start of the string for the first attempt) `\G`
- Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script) `\d*`

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
- Keep the text matched so far out of the overall regex match `\K`
- Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) `\s+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
- Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) `(?=[\d\s]*#)`

  - Match a single character present in the list below `[\d\s]*`

    - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
    - A “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script) `\d`
    - A “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) `\s`
  - Match the character “#” literally `#`

Comment: I couldn't have gotten to such a good solution myself. Thank you. The demo clearly selects correctly all white spaces. Sadly, the replacing does not work: `$input = preg_replace("/(?:#|\G)\d*\K\s+(?=\[\d\s\]*#)/",'',$input);` doesn't replace my white spaces. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @chross Probably a typo. Copy the code in this [demo](http://ideone.com/H9rl0B), it will work (see the output at the bottom of the demo). Also just added a second option in the answer just in case.

Comment: Works flawlessly now. I was not able to spot the typo but the code from your demo did work.
`$regex = "~(?:#|\G)\d*\K\s+(?=[\d\s]*#)~";`
`$input = preg_replace($regex,"",$input);`
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) with the following regex:

```
/^#.*?#:?/m
```

In plain English: assert position at the beginning of the string, match a single `#` character, followed by any character except newlines until the next `#`, matching as minimum as possible (lazy match). Then match a `:`, if found. The `m` modifier is used to enable multi-line matching.

Basically, the expression matches everything in between the first `#` and the second `#`. Once a match is found, it is passed to the callback function where all the spaces are removed using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace).

```
preg_replace_callback('/^#.*?#:?/m', function ($matches) {
    return str_replace(' ', '', $matches[0]);
}, $text);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/157294)